# How to align content to the center of the page?

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a WordPress template, that I used to make a website with. I have a page that I kind of show the companies that work with our company, you can see this here: https://www.haagsehof.nl/onze-klanten/.

[image]

as you can see these are not totally in the middle of the page. I have tried other fixes for this but nothing fix this so far. how can I align the content to the center of the page?

Comment: actually your container that hold the customer boxes ist centered. the problem you have here is that your customer boxes are either too wide if you want 4 in a row or to narrow if you want to have only 3. your .pic class is defining the width, so change it to match the desired outcome

Comment: @Dirk what do u mean what do I have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and Give one common class to all images div and set `background-position:center 0;` for center image

```
.pic {  
    background-position: center 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks, this worked for. can U also help me with soemthing else? if you visit the home page and go to the section `Schoonmaakwerk is mensenwerk`, there is an image on the background how can I ake that scroll able?

Answer (score 1):

Two ways how to ahieve your goal:

1. use this style rules:

   ```
   #lisinOnzeKlanten > li > div{
     width: auto;
   }
   ```

   This will delete spaces on the right side of your copmanies blocks, if will not work , use `width: auto !important;` instead of `width: auto;`. But this option will add your companies count up to 5 in one line.
2. use this one:

   ```
   #lisinOnzeKlanten > li > div{
     background-position: center center;
   }
   ```

   Or use `background-position: center center !important;` instead of `background-position: center center;`, if will not work. This way all background images will be centered without changing width of blocks, or count of companies on one line. But you'll need to fix the hover part, too, to make them centered.

Answer (score 0):

Try these changes.

```
   .pic {
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    background: url(https://www.haagsehof.nl/content/uploads/2018/02/200px-Huawei.svg_.png) center no-repeat;
    }
    #lisinOnzeKlanten {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: -250px;
    text-align: center;
    }
```

Comment: is this really centre?

Comment: in your present code, UL is center aligned-
But <LI> are not. So I put text-align:center-align for this. Then, image inside <LI> was also not centered. So I added 'center' property on background. Not it seems center aligned to me in chrome.

Comment: thanks, I put this code into my css, but I am ot sure if they are actually centrered I think the LI needs to move to the right a little!!

Comment: becasue now the images are not in centre but the text under each image is in the center!!

Comment: try adding a background-color to <LI> so you confirm the position.

Comment: yes you are correct they are in the background, but  each image is not in the centre how do I do that?

Comment: check the styles I posted in answer. You can find "center" inside the background attribute of '.pic'. try adding that.